# How to start Speech Recognition as Soon the Text To Speech stops.

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I want to start Speech Recognition as soon the Text To Speech stops.
following are the steps i have taken.

Step 1 :Initialize Speech Recognition.

```
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(recognitionListener);

    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            Locale.getDefault());
```

Step 2:Initialize Text To Speech.

```
    TextToSpeech myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(myTTS.getEngines().size() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(Robo.this,"No Engines Installed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{


                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Status working.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //message = "How may i help you.";
                    myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    ttsInitialized();
                    speak("what is your name.");
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Step 3:Initialize Utterance Listener to check the Speech is completed or not.

```
    myTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

            //btn.performClick();
            myTTS.shutdown();
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {

        }
    });
```

In the onDone() Method mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent); is used to start the Speech Recognition but it does not start the Speech Recognition.
  Please look into the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Regulus said i added a Handler and it worked.

```
    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                } // This is your code
            };
            mainHandler.post(myRunnable);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The onDone method refers to a specific utterance. This means that if you perform multiple (continuous) calls to the mTTS.speak method, the onDone is called each time. Which obviously can cause serious problems with what you are trying to achieve.

When I had to perform actions after the TTS has finished, I would create a variable like lastUtteranceId, set it to the last queued utterance and checked for a match inside onDone like:

```
if (utteranceId.equals(lastUtteranceId) {
   // TTS finished talking...
}
```

Also, calling shutdown there seems like a bad idea. You should call it on your activity's onDestroy method.

On last thing, I think onDone runs on a background thread and startListening needs to be on the main thread, so check that too.